# Refresh html loaded on div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, load, refresh

I am making a website and I use jQuery to load my html pages inside divs, so the main index html remains intact that way. The problem is that if a user is browsing an html that loads inside a div and tries to refresh his browser(F5) the content gets "lost" since it's only one page(index.html).

Is there a way to get around this?

```
<a onclick='$("#content").load("page1.html");'>Page1</a> 
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: you mean you want to keep showing the content if the user refreshes?

Comment: Do this `$("#content").load("page1.html");` on page load.

Comment: @pXL maybe its not always page1.html but dynamic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two solutions for that. If a user clicks a link, you add a hashtag to the url. For example:

```
<a onclick='$("#content").load("page1.html"); window.location.hash = "page1.html";'>Page1</a>
```

Then, in your jQuery, you check for a hashtag when a user visits the site:

```
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.length) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

        $("#content").load(hash);
    }
});
```

Secondly, you could use cookies but I think the hash way works fine, too :)

Comment: Looks great but still doesn't work for me. Does `window.location.hash = "page1.html";` page1.html must be the same path as the html file? Although I tried that too.

Comment: The hastag is added to the url when you click the link but hitting F5 acts like before, the content doesn't remain there.

Comment: well have you inserted the jquery code in your page? or maybe you have a scripts.js where you can add it?

Comment: Yes I added the script. I am testing it through xampp by the way. The html files are not in the same folder with index though, does that have to do anything with this not working?

Comment: do you get any errors? because this is really simple and should work perfectly. just to make clear: you have jquery, right after that you have a custom .js file/ or inline js with the above code, right?

Comment: Yes: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash.length) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        $("#content").load(hash);
    }
});
</script>`

Comment: looking good. still you get now errors? try to add a console.log within the function, like so:
...
var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
console.log(hash);

Comment: I added this but don't see anything happen, no errors whatsoever.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30390/discussion-between-zefs-and-alex)