# Ajax $_get search terms lost after user clicks on result

Tags: php, ajax, search, get

Ive got a member search form that searches users on my site. The form method is get.

The results are displayed using Ajax on the same page. The page is not reloaded.

If a user clicks on a search result, then the appropriate page is opened in the same tab.

The problem comes when a user clicks back. Because the search result has opened in the same tab, clicking back returns you to the page with the search form, but all search results are lost. The user therefore has to start the search again.

The only solution i can think of is to not use ajax and post the search terms to the url. But thats not ideal.

Anyone got any better solutions - somehow storing the get variable so that ajax can pick it up again?

Comment: You probably could use sessions and/or cookies. Wait for more comments.

Comment: pls check this link it may help you ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686448/refresh-html-loaded-on-div-using-jquery/16686669#16686669

Comment: You could use something along the lines of: `$results = $_GET['search_results'];` - `if (isset($_GET['search_results'])) { // execute code... using $results variable }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you used 'history.back()' for back button. You should use get or post to pass inputed variable of user to form search.

Comment: This is not a viable solution. The user just may decide to use the back button instead, so it has to be done via server-side and not client-side.

Comment: But if you have a back button which is easy to use, user won't use browser back button.

Comment: You would be surprised as to how hard-headed people can be! lol